# Looking for example of a group

Tags: group-theory

I'm looking for a group $G$ that is not nilpotent but has a nilpotent Frattini quotient $G/\Phi(G)$. Such a group would have to be necessarily infinite.

Comment: Thompson's group F.

Comment: I think it's also true in the Grigorchuk group. The maximal subgroups all have index 2, and $G/\Phi(G)$ is elementary abelian of order 8.